# Pre-images of functions, subsets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let f:X→Y be a function.Consider sets A⊆Y and B⊆Y.Show that if A⊆B,then f^(-1)(A)⊆f^(-1) (B)

I have assumed A⊆B and let x be arbitrary in f^(-1)(A), and know that the statement is true but it seems simple and obvious and I am unsure how to prove it so need help as to how I would lay it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f:X\to Y$ and $C\subset Y$. By definition,
$$f^{-1}(C):=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in C\}\subset Y.$$

So let prove your statement:

$$x\in f^{-1}(A)\implies f(x)\in A\subset B\implies f(x)\in B\implies x\in f^{-1}(B)$$